# How to check whether a value is exist or not in Firestore Database with Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Sign-Up Screen. On that screen, I get Username, Email, and Password. The Firestore API automatically checks if the Email is in use or not but I want to show the user if the Username entered is in use or not. To do it I used this code snippet :

```
fun userExists(element1 : String, element2 : String) : Boolean {

val db : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
val dbUsers : CollectionReference = db.collection("user")
var isExists : Boolean = false

dbUsers.whereEqualTo(element1, element2).get().addOnSuccessListener {
    // if true it is empty and it is not exists.
    isExists = it.documents.isNotEmpty()
}
return isExists
```

but here it skips and continues without returning the correct value. When I try this separately it works fine I understand if data exists or not but when I use it like this it doesn't work. I have tried adding await() but it also has not worked. To run it under @Composable function I made the function suspend first after that I called this userExists function under rememberCoroutine but also couldn't run it. The thing I want is simply checking for example userName: user1234 exists or not.
Thanks in advance.

Edit : Whole code.

```
 @OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SignUpScreen(navigation: NavController, auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    var userName by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var userEmail by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var password by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf("") }
    var passwordVisible by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val context = LocalContext.current
    val sharedPrefMail = context.getSharedPreferences("userEmail", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val sharedPrefName = context.getSharedPreferences("userName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val sharedPrefScore = context.getSharedPreferences("highScore", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val db : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val dbUsers : CollectionReference = db.collection("user")

    val buttonSize = with(LocalDensity.current) {
        (300f).toDp()
}
Column(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .padding(vertical = buttonSize),
    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
) {
    {...}
    // Toast message is not shown. Use PopUp message
    Button(onClick = {

        if (userEmail == "" || password == "" || userName == "") {
            Toast.makeText(context, "PLEASE ENTER EMAIL, USERNAME AND PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else if (userExists("userName", userName)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "USERNAME IS IN USE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        } else {
            auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, password).addOnSuccessListener {
                // User creation is successful
                val user = UserObj(userEmail, userName, "0")
                dbUsers.add(user).addOnSuccessListener {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USER CREATED SUCCESSFULLY", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    sharedPrefMail.edit().putString("userMail", userEmail).apply()
                    sharedPrefName.edit().putString("userName", userName).apply()
                    sharedPrefScore.edit().putString("highScore", "0").apply()
                }
                navigation.navigate("FirstScreen")
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(context, "COULDN'T CREATE USER", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                println(it.localizedMessage)
            }


        }

    },
        modifier = Modifier.size(buttonSize, buttonSize/3)
    ) {
        Text("SIGN UP")
    }
}
}
```

Comment: try `var isExists by mutableStateOf(false)` instead. And if that doesn't work, return the `State` object instead.

Comment: I tried with mutableStateOf it didn't work. How can I return the State object ?

Comment: Aside from my answer, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-read-data-from-cloud-firestore-using-get-bf03b6ee4953) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/CloudFirestore/).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return `isExists` as a result of a function. Firebase API is asynchronous. To solve this, you have to use a solution that is always the same. Any code that needs data from Firestore, needs to be inside the `onSuccess()` function or be called from there. However, a more modern approach will be to use [Kotlin Coroutines](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-overview.html).

> I have tried adding await() but it also did not work.

This sentence doesn't provide enough information so we can help. However, when you call [await()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/await.html) it means that it will always await the completion of the task without blocking a thread. Please note that this function is a `suspend` function and **not** a `blocking` function. So your function should look like this:

```
fun userExists(element1 : String, element2 : String) : Boolean {
    val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val dbUsers: CollectionReference = db.collection("user")

    return dbUsers.whereEqualTo(element1, element2).get().await().isEmpty
}
```

This method will check if the result of the query is empty or not.

Comment: Actually I am using this in an if else statement. if (userExists("userName","test")) { Toast.makeText...("this user is exist") } I am showing a message like this. Here when I use await() system wants me to change function to "suspend fun" after I change the function in if else statement I get this error " Suspend function 'userExists' should be called only from a coroutine or another suspend function " because of this I can not proceed on await()

Comment: A suspend function should be called from within a suspend function or a coroutine. I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-make-a-clean-architecture-android-app-using-mvvm-firestore-and-jetpack-compose-abdb5e02a2d8) will help understand how this works in a simple application. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirestoreCleanArchitectureApp).

Comment: Hey Yunus. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your help. I found the solution in another resource. Actually your answer was correct but to implement it I needed some extra solution. So I specified all in my answer.

Comment: So you basically used my function, right?

Comment: Yes your code is correct but it is not enough to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it this way because it's an asynchronous operation. Bu you can do it like this using flow and suspend functions.

```
suspend fun isUserExists(element1: String, element2: String) = callbackFlow {
        try {
            val db: FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
            val dbUsers: CollectionReference = db.collection("user")

            dbUsers.whereEqualTo(element1, element2).get()
                .addOnSuccessListener {
                    trySendBlocking(it.documents.isNotEmpty())
                }.addOnFailureListener {
                    // your error action
                }

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
```

And collect like this,

```
viewModel.isUserExists().collect { isUserNameExist ->
    //
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Before @Faruk Karaca's answer I solved the problem. I am specifying this because it may work as well idk.

Here is the whole code :

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun SignUpScreen(navigation: NavController, auth: FirebaseAuth) {
    val db : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val dbUsers : CollectionReference = db.collection("user")

    val mainScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(vertical = buttonSize),
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        
        Button(onClick = {
            mainScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) { // important
                if (userEmail == "" || password == "" || userName == "") {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "PLEASE ENTER EMAIL, USERNAME AND PASSWORD", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else if (userExists("userName", userName)) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "USERNAME IS IN USE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userEmail, password).addOnSuccessListener {
                        val user = UserObj(userEmail, userName, "0")
                        dbUsers.add(user).addOnSuccessListener {
                            // Successful processes
                        }
                        navigation.navigate("FirstScreen")
                    }.addOnFailureListener {
                        //Failure processes
                    }
                }
            }
        },
            modifier = Modifier.size(buttonSize, buttonSize/3)
        ) {
            Text("SIGN UP")
        }
    }
    }

suspend fun userExists(element1 : String, element2 : String) : Boolean {
    val db : FirebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val dbUsers : CollectionReference = db.collection("user")

    return !dbUsers.whereEqualTo(element1, element2).get().await().isEmpty

}
```

Under mainScope.launch I implemented my suspend function.